# Yii2 Multiple caching storage

Tags: php, caching, yii2

Is it possible to use two or more caching storage in yii2 framework? I already setup a Memcache for my web app but I wanted also to use a FileCache since I will be dealing with a large chunk of data.

hope someone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set any cache. Just set it at config file.

```
'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
   'memCache' => [
        'class' => 'MEMCACHE CLASS HERE',
    ],
    .... ANY cache you want ...
 ]
```

Comment: I see. I will try to set that up. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can register multiple cache application components. The component named cache is used by default by many cache-dependent classes (e.g. yii\web\UrlManager).

Official [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html)

```
'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',

    ],
   'fileCache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ]
   ]
```